# How to take action on certain keystrokes in TextBox?

Tags: wpf, textbox

I have a WPF window with a text box. I'd like to detect when a user presses either the Enter key or Tab key. When either of these keys are pressed, I'd like to bind to an action in our view model. Could someone show me how this can be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Handle the `KeyDown` event.

```
<TextBox KeyDown="TextBox_KeyDown"/>
```

```
private void TextBox_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.Key)
    {
        case Key.Enter:
            vw.Method1();
            break;
        case Key.Tab:
            vw.Method2();
            break;
        default:
    }
}
```

Or use commands:

```
public static class Commands
{
    public static RoutedCommand Command1 = new RoutedCommand();
    public static RoutedCommand Command2 = new RoutedCommand();
}
```

```
 <TextBox>
     <TextBox.CommandBindings>
         <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static local:Commands.Command1}"
                         Executed="Command1_Executed" CanExecute="Command1_CanExecute"/>
         <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static local:Commands.Command2}"
                         Executed="Command2_Executed" CanExecute="Command2_CanExecute"/>
     </TextBox.CommandBindings>
     <TextBox.InputBindings>
         <KeyBinding Key="Enter" Command="{x:Static local:Commands.Command1}"/>
         <KeyBinding Key="Tab" Command="{x:Static local:Commands.Command2}"/>
     </TextBox.InputBindings>
 </TextBox>
```

If you have not used commands before make sure to read [this overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752308.aspx).

Comment: Just be careful: Tab is used for keyboard navigation (focus the next UI control), which is needed to make the program accessible.

Comment: True, but in a TextBox it can also have a different function than navigating so it might be excusable to do something with it here. Maybe there should be an option to turn it off though, there are probably guidelines for that stuff somewhere...